# kubernetes gluster volume failing to mount with error “failed to get the 'volume file' from server”

Tags: glusterfs, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We are running a pod in kubernetes on container engine that just started to to fail in the container creating stage with the following error message?

Has anyone seen such an error before? Any suggestions on how to fix?

```
Mounting command: /home/kubernetes/bin/mounter
Mounting arguments: <one-of-our-gluster-internal-ips>:gluster-volume-0 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/7dd7d1e1-d202-11e6-84b4-42010a80008d/volumes/kubernetes.io~glusterfs/glusterfsvol glusterfs [log-level=ERROR log-file=/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/glusterfs/glusterfsvol/certificate-manager-deployment-2775235973-71fyd-glusterfs.log]
Output: Running mount using a rkt fly container
run: group "rkt" not found, will use default gid when rendering images
WARNING: getfattr not found, certain checks will be skipped..
Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.

 the following error information was pulled from the glusterfs log to help diagnose this issue:
[2017-01-03 22:18:42.934340] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1503:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-glusterfs: failed to get the 'volume file' from server
[2017-01-03 22:18:42.934393] E [glusterfsd-mgmt.c:1603:mgmt_getspec_cbk] 0-mgmt: failed to fetch volume file (key:gluster-volume-0)
```

- kubernetes 1.4.7
- gluster 3.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this up as I was unable to find anything else online. It turns out that I had a few bricks fail to come online that I missed. Followed the answer here and got it up again: [Gluster bricks are offline and errors in logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/442096/gluster-bricks-are-offline-and-errors-in-logs)